# Error During anonymization DB postgres using dataDefender

Tags: postgresql, anonymize

After analyze my db using DataDefender and during i anonymized it ,i faced an exception !

you can find the error description below:

```
Desktop\DataDefender\sample_projects\database_discovery\postgresql>java -jar datadefender.jar anonymize @database.config -r=anonymize.xml

Starting anonymizer
Anonymizing table public.ouvrage_oeuvre...   5% │███████                                                                                                                             │   999/18715 (0:00:00 / 0:00:10)

[ERROR] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 UPDATE public.ouvrage_oeuvre SET internalcomment_ = NULL, origin_ = NULL, place_ = NULL, status_ = 'Vestibulum tristique tortor luctus urna dapibus dignissim.' WHERE id_ = '19002'  was aborted: 
  ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 131  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

[ERROR] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

  Position: 131
[ERROR] Exception anonymizing table
```

anyone have an idea please?

Comment: Whatever that code is doing it tries to compare a number with a string and Postgres doesn't allow that. Given the SQL statement, most probably `WHERE id_ = '19002'` should be `WHERE id_ = 19002`

Comment: Thanks for replying , The issue is clear , this error generated by the tool datadefender so i dont know how to fix it

Comment: You should file an issue with the project. That's simply sloppy programming